# Nginx - config to route to single page app

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx with the deployment of my website on my local server.

The website is a single page create react app running on the server. I have a domain, [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) for example, and i want the single page app to be found on [www.test.com/first-website](http://www.test.com/first-website). From reading online I'm supposed to use the rewrite directive.

This is my current config:

```
http {
        upstream sensory-showcase {
                server 127.0.0.1:5000;
        }

        server {
                listen 80;

                location /sensory-solution-for-firefighters {
                        rewrite ^/sensory-solution-for-firefighters $1 break;
                        proxy_pass http://sensory-showcase/;
                }
        }
}

events { }
```

From this the url resolves without an nginx 500 error however it just shows a blank white page.
And i have to have a trailing `/`, eg [www.test.com/first-website/](http://www.test.com/first-website/) . Without the trailing `/` it errors.

I just note, when I didnt have the `rewrite` directive in, and left the location at just `/` the site loaded fine.

Comment: Are you using another webservice to serve your html files ? I mean whats running on port 5000 ?

Comment: `rewrite` is required only if your React router is working in `history` mode - so that it always serves `index.html` even if you try to directly open some route. No `rewrite` is needed in `hash` mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will fallback to the index.html of your single page app, which will do the routing:

```
       location /first-website {
            try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /first-website/index.html;
       }
```